# Summation notation for the "ij'th" entry of matrix $(AB)^t$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm just trying to figure out how to write out a formula to find the ij'th entry of the transpose of a matrix product.

We have an $l \times m$ matrix $B$ and an $m \times n$ matrix $A$. We have

$B = \begin{matrix} b_{11} & b_{12} & \cdots & b_{1m} \\ b_{21} & b_{22} & \cdots & b_{2m}\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ b_{l1} & b_{l2} & \cdots & b_{lm} \\ \end{matrix}$

$A = \begin{matrix} a_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1n} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{2m}\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ a_{m1} & a_{m2} & \cdots & a_{mn} \\ \end{matrix}$

Then, we can find the ij'th entry of the product BA by:

- $\sum_{k=1}^{m}b_{ik}a_{kj}$

Now let's take the transpose of $A$ and $B$:

$B^t = \begin{matrix} b_{11} & b_{21} & \cdots & b_{l1} \\ b_{12} & b_{22} & \cdots & b_{2m}\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ b_{1m} & b_{lm} & \cdots & b_{lm} \\ \end{matrix}$

$A^t = \begin{matrix} a_{11} & a_{21} & \cdots & a_{m1} \\ a_{12} & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{m2}\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ a_{1n} & a_{2n} & \cdots & a_{mn} \\ \end{matrix}$

However, this is when I start to get confused. When we take the transpose what changes in the original summation we used to find the ij'th entry in BA? Do we just reverse the order of $i$ and  $j$:

- $\sum_{k=1}^{m}b_{jk}a_{ki}$?

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $[AB]_{ab} = \sum_k [A]_{ak} [B]_{kb}$, you have
$[(AB)^T]_{ab} = [AB]_{ba} = \sum_k [A]_{bk} [B]_{ka}$.